# Products packaging approach database model

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-relations

I have this structure for my products process.

1 - In 'product' table the identity of the products are defined.

2 - In 'product_pack' table the identity of packs which must be have the products inside 
them defined.

3 - In 'pack_content' table,each pack that have products with counts.

4 - In 'pack_stock' the stocks of each packs stored with same or different package type(each of packages are a row).

5 - In 'pack_stok_content' the contents of pack_stock records with facor buy number are stored.

I want to know is this the right way to go or my model is wrong or is there any better model or solution for this?

`CREATE TABLE products (
  id int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  barCode varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  prodName varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  stock double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  unit_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY barCode (barCode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;`

`CREATE TABLE product_pack (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  label varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  count float NOT NULL,
  base_price int(11) NOT NULL,
  price int(11) NOT NULL,
  stock float NOT NULL,
  status tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  percentage double DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY id (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;`

`CREATE TABLE pack_content (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  pack_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  product_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  count int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY pack_id (pack_id),
  KEY product_id (product_id),
  CONSTRAINT pack_content_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (pack_id) REFERENCES product_pack (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT pack_content_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;`

`CREATE TABLE pack_stock (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  pack_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  isSelled bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY pack_id (pack_id),
  CONSTRAINT pack_stock_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (pack_id) REFERENCES product_pack (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;`

`CREATE TABLE pack_stock_content (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  pack_stock_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  factor_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  count int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY pack_stock_id (pack_stock_id),
  KEY factor_id (factor_id),
  CONSTRAINT pack_stock_content_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (pack_stock_id) REFERENCES pack_stock (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT pack_stock_content_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (factor_id) REFERENCES new_prefactor (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;`

`CREATE TABLE new_prefactor (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  product_source_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  product_arrival_date int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  factor_registration_date int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  factor_registration_number int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  date int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  image varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  description varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  price int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  status int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  payment_type_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY status (status),
  KEY product_source_id (product_source_id),
  KEY payment_type_id (payment_type_id),
  CONSTRAINT new_prefactor_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (status) REFERENCES factor_status (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT new_prefactor_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (product_source_id) REFERENCES product_source (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT new_prefactor_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY (payment_type_id) REFERENCES payment_type (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: What is a "pack"?  What will the main `SELECTs` be?

Comment: @RickJames, Pack is a package contains some products in it and `pack_content` table have the pack containers.